# How to let Idea comment my comments in xml right?

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, tags, comments, hotkeys

I am using Idea to manage my spring project. It uses mybatis for ORM. When I was working on a mapper XML file, I added some comments, marked them, and hit `ctrl + /` to comment that line, the comments are commentted with a `#` sign at the start of line.

```
            ...
            <if test="cm.timeTipEnd != null">
                <![CDATA[and r.create_time <= #{cm.timeTipEnd}]]>
            </if>
#            My comments explaining the next if below
            <if test="cm.writersId != null and cm.writersId != ''">
            ...
```

Then I tried the block comment hotkey, `ctrl + shift + /`, and `/* */` shows up!

```
            <if test="cm.timeTipEnd != null">
                <![CDATA[and r.create_time <= #{cm.timeTipEnd}]]>
            </if>
            /*My comments explaining the next if below*/
            <if test="cm.writersId != null and cm.writersId != ''">
            ...
```

What I want is `<!--My comments explaining the next if below-->`, though. Is there a way to fix this?
I noticed if I select some xml tags and hit the comment key, it would be comment right. However, my comments don't need xml tags.

Edit:
a gif demonstration of me adding line comment and block comment to a select statement in mybatis mapper(not working), and doing the same thing to a `select` tag(working)
[image]
My idea log file: [download link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NQcsQp34XPHcUMJgbzF7u1K81iafb3nm/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and some sample project example?

Comment: @y.bedrov I added a screenshot gif and shared my log file. However, I doubt the log file could be any help.

Comment: Is it reproducible with custom plugins disabled: Loaded custom plugins: One Dark theme (5.1.5), Gradianto (4.4), Solarized Theme (3.0.0), IDE Eval Reset (2.1.13), Grep Console (11.6.202.000.0), IDEA Jetty Runner (1.4.14), Alibaba Java Coding Guidelines (2.1.0), Kotlin (203-1.4.31-release-IJ7148.5), Free MyBatis plugin (2020.12.18)

Comment: @y.bedrov I tried turning off plugins. It turned out turning off the plugin `Database Tools and SQL` and turning it back on solves this issue. I also turned on the plugins that depends on it cause they were turned off when I turned off the database plugin.